# Определение концов дуг на одноцветном фоне

Tags: математика

Есть изображение - фон синего цвета, на нем есть одноцветные дуги кругов разного радиуса(от 20 до 40), дуги имеют длину половину круга, могут накладыватся друг на друга. Задача - вычислить координаты концов дуг, то есть массив [{x: начало дуги; y: конец дуги}]. Чтобы потом можно было провести между ними линию и закрасить превратив картинку в набор из полукругов.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, немного поразмышляем над задачей. Мне помогает листок бумаги и ручка. Рисуя разные дуги, можно заметить, что частично перекрывающие друг друга дуги могут создать трудности. Например две дуги одинакового цвета и радиуса могут образовать окружность, и тогда найти их концы будет невозможно. Если задача не требует совершенно точного результата и является прикладной (то есть *достаточно* точный результат тоже будет полезен), то сосредоточимся на простых случаях.

Попробуем решить задачу для одной дуги.

[image: дуга]

Как выглядит её конец, который мы ищем?

[image: конец дуги]

Что его отличает от других частей дуги? С трёх смежных сторон у него фон. Чтобы увидеть эти стороны, необходимо рассматривать часть изображения вокруг точки дуги. Если все дуги нарисованы линиями одной толщины, то кажется разумным уменьшить изображение до такого размера, чтобы их толщина равнялась одному пикселю. Моя дуга нарисована линией толщиной в один пиксель, поэтому смежные стороны -- это соседние пиксели.

Что получается:

1. Обходим всё изображение в поисках точек дуг.
2. Для каждой точки дуги, рассматриваем соседние пиксели. Если соседние пиксели разделяют фон на две области, то это не конец дуги, иначе мы нашли, что искали.

С несколькими дугами задача усложняется: найденные точки надо объединить в пары. В вашем случае то, что дуги имеют ограниченную длину и являются полуокружностями может помочь. А я упрощу себе задачу, раскрасив дуги разными цветами.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(60, 70, 60, -0.2 * Math.PI, 0.8 * Math.PI);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 110, 70, -0.8 * Math.PI, -0.3 * Math.PI);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#0f0';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 30);
ctx.lineTo(120, 100);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
ctx.stroke();

var ArcsFinder = function() {

    this.find = function(imageData, bgRgb) {
        var around = [
            [-1, -1],
            [0, -1],
            [1, -1],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [0, 1],
            [-1, 1],
            [-1, 0]

        ];
        var endings = [];
        var dots = _getDots(imageData.data, bgRgb);
        for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; ++i) {
            var x = dots[i] % imageData.width;
            var y = Math.trunc(dots[i] / imageData.height);
            var nBg =[];
            for (var j = 0; j < around.length; ++j) {
                var nx = x + around[j][0];
                var ny = y + around[j][1];
                if (
                    nx >= 0
                    && nx < imageData.width
                    && ny >= 0
                    && ny < imageData.height
                ) {
                    var nd = (
                        dots[i]
                        + (
                            (around[j][1] * imageData.width)
                            + around[j][0]
                        )
                    ) * 4;
                    nBg.push(_isBg(
                        [
                            imageData.data[nd],
                            imageData.data[nd + 1],
                            imageData.data[nd + 2]
                        ],
                        bgRgb
                    ));
                } else {
                    nBg.push(true);
                }
            }

            if (_countIntervals(nBg) === 1) {
                endings.push([x, y]);
            }  
        }

        return endings;
    };

    function _getDots(data, bgRgb) {
        var dots = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i += 4) {
            if ( ! _isBg([data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2]], bgRgb)) {
                dots.push(i / 4);
            }
        }

        return dots;
    }

    function _isBg(rgb, bgRgb) {
        var diff = (
            Math.abs(rgb[0] - bgRgb[0])
            + Math.abs(rgb[1] - bgRgb[1])
            + Math.abs(rgb[2] - bgRgb[2])
        );
        
        return diff < 255;
    }

    function _countIntervals(n)
    {
        var noise = 0;
        var c = 0;
        var lastN = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
            if ( ! n[i]) {
                ++noise;
            }
            if (lastN && ! n[i]) {
                ++c;
            }
            lastN = n[i];
        }

        if (noise >= n.length / 2) {
            // если точек относящихся к дуге половина или больше,
            // то это какая-то каша из дуг
            return noise;
        }

        if ( ! n[0] && n[0] === n[n.length - 1]) {
            --c;
        }

        return c;
    }
};

var btnEl = document.getElementById('findBtn'); 
btnEl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.prevetDefault;
    var finder = new ArcsFinder();
    var endings = finder.find(
        ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
        [0, 0, 255]
    );
    console.log(endings);
    for (var i = 0; i < endings.length; ++i) {
        var ending = endings[i];
        var px = ctx.getImageData(ending[0], ending[1], 1, 1);
        var data = px.data;
        var rgb = 'rgb(' + data[0] + ', ' + data[1] + ', ' + data[2] + ')';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(ending[0], ending[1], 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.strokeStyle = rgb;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    btnEl.remove();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<button id="findBtn">find endigs</button>
```

Это очень примитивный подход и тут есть большой простор для оптимизаций. Кроме того, возможно я где-то допустил ошибки. Но надеюсь, что я задал направление вашей мысли.

Математика пока не пригодилась. Но возможно пригодится при оптимизациях.